# How to export customers from Magento into WooCommerce (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

I'm in the process of moving Magento store into WooCommerce.

The problem is that Magento and Wordpress has different password autentificacion algorithm.

The way magento store the password: `md5($salt.$password).':'.$salt;`

The way Wordpress store the password: `md5($password)`

Is there way to export existing Magento customers into worpdress and keep their passwords ?

Comment: Not without modifying the password check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that is a one way encryption that would not be possible.  Your best bet would be to modify the Wordpress store to use the same encryption used by Magento.

Comment: Thanks! that's what I figured - I have to overwrite wordpress auth functions

Comment: @tokmak  You probably don't need to overwrite the entire Wordpress authentication functions, you just need to change out the logic to use a salted password, with salt being generated as per Magento. You would of course also need to store the salt in the database.  This should actually be a relatively trivial task.

Comment: I wrote little WP plugin which accept magento passwords with salt

Comment: Can i try your plugin?

Comment: sure, send me your email - I'll share with you

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very old post, but have found the following solution:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-user-compatibility/
Its a plugin that, upon login, tests the entered password against the Magento hash, if that is successful, it re-hashes the password WordPress style and saves that to the database and proceeds with login.

Credits to this post that helped me out a lot: http://www.iancboswell.com/?p=122